# How to use weight of a deep neural network which is trained in tensorflow-python api in a c++ project?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have trained some classification models with tensorflow 2.4 and now I want to use these trained models in a c++ project. I did similar work by tkDNN library(which is used to increase frame per second (fps)) but in this case I don't want to use tkDNN because I don't care about fps.
In the below code I used weight of trained yolo-tiny which is fixed point by tkDNN. Is there any library for feeding weights like this code to use dnn in c++?

```
int main()
{

int n_classes=3;

const char * net = "/home/tkDNN/build/yolo_tiny_3l_fp16.rt";

// instantiate detector
tk::dnn::Yolo3Detection yolo;
tk::dnn::DetectionNN *detNN;
detNN = &yolo;
int n_batch = 2;
detNN->init(net, n_classes, n_batch);


bool g;
g = true;
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
if(!cap.isOpened())
    g = false;
else
    std::cout<<"camera started\n";

...
```

Comment: You probably want to use something like ONNX to export your model from python. ONNX has a C++ runtime that can then load your model and perform inference.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge @Wacov. Could you please provide a link of an example about that?  I searched but I didn't find a clear concept or example about that.

Comment: Haven't actually done this myself but this is where I'd start:
https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx
https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime
I think the essence of it is that you export a .onnx file then load and use that in C++ with onnxruntime.

Comment: Thank you so much @Wacov. It seems to help. I want to test it now.